# How to call freebase api using nodejs ExpressJS or Superagent

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, freebase, superagent

I have [this](http://tinyurl.com/kr8flbm) Freebase query and need to use it in NodeJS + ExpressJS or NodeJS + [Superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). I tried [Google API](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) module and the [Freebase module](https://github.com/spencermountain/Freebase.js) (that doesn't npm install!), but i'm very confuse about how to use. I dig into google and documentation without success. I already have my Google Freebase API Key and read in some web posts that always need to use it and in others that it's not necessary. I'm very confuse about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future generations who google here like I did, the npm module is now working and appears to be awesome.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/freebase